# changing script src onclick, will it execute once the page has loaded?

Tags: javascript

So lets say I have a script that loads immediately when you load a page.

But when you click on a button, the script src changes. Will that new src get executed?

HTML

```
<button>
click
</button>

<script class="tracking" src="www.gamespot.com"></script>
```

Javascript

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "script",
    success: console.log("success")
    });
});

var url = "www.test.com";
```

I was actually thinking of appending the second script into the DOM when the button is clicked, but the results are funky on jsfiddle for some reason, so I'm not sure if that works..

Comment: As you seem to be using jQuery, you could just use [`$.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: hmm I made an edit to the javascript above. would that work? I did it via '$.ajax()'. sorry, I read that '$.getScript()' is a shorthand for ajax, which I learned a little bit about a few months ago heh

Comment: Probably the same thing, but `$.getScript` is shorter. Changing the source or inserting the script tag should work fine as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org)

Would be something like this:

```
var url = "www.test.com";

$("button").on("click",function(){
    require(url, function() {
        // callback that is executed after the script is loaded
    });
});
```